# Solving a single-term recurrence relation with a variable coefficient?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$a_n = 2na_{n-1}\\
a_0 = 1$

How do I solve this? Is there a characteristic equation? I found $a_1 = 2, a_2 = 8, a_3 = 48$ but I don't know what to do with that information to solve.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what to try. It's not homework. I just want to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that 
$$a_n=2na_{n-1}=2n\cdot(2(n-1)a_{n-2})=2n\cdot(2(n-1)\cdot(2(n-2)a_{n-3}))=...=2^{n-1}n!a_1$$
but $$a_1=2\cdot1\cdot a_0=2$$
Hence 
$$a_n=2^nn!$$

Comment: Is there any other way of getting the solution? I don't notice that.

Comment: $a_3=2\cdot 3 \cdot a_2=2\cdot 3\cdot 8=2^3\cdot 3!$

Answer (score 0):

solving the equation $q^n=2q^{n-1}$ we get $q=2$ thus the equation has the form $$a_n=C2^n$$ you will get the value of $$C$$ by inserting an initional condition.

Comment: Actually sorry I left out a major part of the problem, i.e., the variable coefficient, n... check now?

Answer (score 0):

This is a linear recurrence of the first order. Say you have:

$\begin{align*}
  w_{n + 1}
    &= a_n w_n + f_n
\end{align*}$

Then you can divide by the *summing factor* $a_n a_{n - 1} \dotsb a_0$ (assuming none is zero) and get:

$\begin{align*}
  \frac{w_{n + 1}}{a_n a_{n - 1} \dotsb a_0}
     - \frac{w_n}{a_{n - 1} \dotsb a_0}
     &= \frac{f_n}{a_n a_{n - 1} \dotsc a_0} \\
  \sum_{0 \le k \le n - 1}
    \left(
      \frac{w_{k + 1}}{a_k a_{k - 1} \dotsb a_0}
        - \frac{w_k}{a_{k - 1} \dotsb a_0}
    \right)
     &= \sum_{0 \le k \le n - 1} \frac{f_k}{a_k a_{k - 1} \dotsc a_0} \\
 \frac{w_n}{a_{n - 1} \dotsb a_0} - w_0
     &= \sum_{0 \le k \le n - 1} \frac{f_k}{a_k a_{k - 1} \dotsc a_0}
\end{align*}$

A general formula is a mess.

In your particular case, the summing factor is just $2^n n!$, $a_0 = 1$, $f_n = 0$, and the solution is just:

$\begin{align*}
a_n = 2^n n!
\end{align*}$